# How to write a custom Flat File Item Reader

Tags: spring, spring-batch, flat-file

I am new to Spring batch. I wanted to ask how can I write a custom flat file item reader in Spring batch.
I know there is one generic FlatFileItemReader available in Spring batch, but we want to add some business logic while reading then how to write a custom flat file reader.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's is what you want to accomplish...a `FlatFileItemReader` will read from a file; I'm not sure what you meant by _we want to add some business logic while reading_

Comment: The spring-batch tags are most appropriate for this question. The 'batch-file' tag gives the following description. "A batch file is a text file containing a series of commands that are executed by the command interpreter on DOS, OS/2, or Microsoft Windows systems."

Comment: What is the the business logic you are trying to add?  Remember that all the FlatFileItemReader does is read lines from a file based on what the given line separator is and passes them to a given LineMapper.  Is this really the point at which you need your business logic?

Comment: Hi, I want to achieve following functionality  - 1. In xml file if I define flatfilereader then I am not able to debug my program where it fails, I want to write this reader in java or extend the existing one..And I want to put loggers in my reader to get the better control on program.

Answer (score 1):

I have done same thing for MultiResourceItemReader, you can extend FlatFileReader and copy complete code of FlatFileReader. Then you can add your own method.

Answer (score 0):

If the in-build logging provided in the FlatFileItemReader is not sufficient for your needs,

1. Grab the code for the FlatFileItemReader - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.java
2. Rename the class to you class-name/package name
3. Add loggers as needed and use

I don't recommend this - in more cases you would be better off debugging your code with a debugger.